# Add dynamic email address in CC Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I would like to send out Reminder Emails via a Journey. For the Second Reminder in the Journey the Manager of the email receiver should be on CC. As there are different Managers for all the people who are entering the Journey, the CC must be personalized via AMP Script.

Support has enabled the CC and BCC in Journey Builder. But whenever I try to add personalization String in CC field (Under Email Send Definition in Journey Builder) - it throws an error : 'Enter a valid email address'.

Can anyone help me with the use case Or suggest any other viable solution?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, so others can see this has been answered correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible currently. To make salesforce aware of the need for this feature you could post this feature request to [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).